# Find matching keywords in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, keyword, matching

I have a nested dictionary like:

```
data = {
    'level1a': {'level2a':[1,2,3]},
    'level1b': {'level2b':[4,5,6]},
    'level1c': {'level2a':[7,8,9]}
}
```

Now i would like to find and sum up the 2 lists with the same level 2 keyword ('level2a'). The result should be something like:

```
[8, 10, 12]
```

Is there some efficient way to do that?

Comment: Do you only want the values related to key `'level2a'` or any key on level2?

Comment: After reading the answer from @Óscar López and your question I realize that I may have formulated the question a bit unhappy. Sorry for that. 
I actually don't know the matching keywords in my list. So the whole point is to find all the matching ones and then sum them up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import add
data = {
    'level1a': {'level2a':[1,2,3]},
    'level1b': {'level2b':[4,5,6]},
    'level1c': {'level2a':[7,8,9]}
}
c = Counter()
dic = {}
for k,v in data.iteritems():
    for k1, v1 in v.iteritems():
        c[k1] += 1
        val = dic.setdefault(k1, [0]*len(v1))
        dic[k1] = map(add, v1, val)

for k,v  in c.iteritems():
    if v > 1:
        print dic[k]
```

**Output:**

```
[8, 10, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
result=[]

for first_key, first_value in data.iteritems():
    for second_key, second_value in first_value.iteritems():
        if second_key == 'level2a':
            if result == []:
                result += second_value
            else:
                result=[result[i] + value for i,value in enumerate(second_value)]
```

This will iterate through each of them checking for the correct key in thes second level dicts.  The if/else loop determines if any items have been added to the result already.  If so, it will increment the values according to the next list in 'level2a'.  This also assumes that all second level lists are the same length, otherwise you will have trailing values in `result` that won't be incremented.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
>>> data = {
...     'level1a': {'level2a':[1,2,3]},
...     'level1b': {'level2b':[4,5,6]},
...     'level1c': {'level2a':[7,8,9]}
... }
>>>
>>> def sum_matches(data, match):
...     inner = data.itervalues()
...     matches = (x[match] for x in inner if match in x)
...     return [sum(x) for x in zip(*matches)]
...
>>>
>>> sum_matches(data, 'level2a')
[8, 10, 12]
```